# Android : game interface

Tags: android, interface, drawing

in my game id like to have some interface at the bottom of the screen,
 like XP bar, health status etc.

should i create a custom XML view to hold game SurfaceView (to draw the game) and
SurfaceView to draw interface and then share data between two classes
(one huge frame layout for game drawing, and smaller frame layout for interface)

or draw the interface directly on the game canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the interface up in several smaller custom views (probably inheriting from imageview, or progress-bar for the xp-bar) and then put it all in a relative layout. And have the relative and the gameview in a frameview.

Comment: ok, thanks and what should i use to share data between the game renderer and interface one, just a reference or some shared preferences stuff or something else??